# Access 2007 one-to-two columns referential integrity

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Setup:
One table called `documents` with columns `author_id` and `reviewer_id` (among others).
One table called `users` with column `user_id`.

I need to create two referential integrity links:
One-to-many between `user_id` and `author_id`.
One-to-many between `user_id` and `reviewer_id`.

In other words, these two columns in `documents` are independent of one another, but both should have a value that is a valid `user_id`.

Adding either one of these relationships works fine. When I try to add a second relationship in the `Edit Relationships` window, Access complains with the following message:

*Microsoft Office Access can't enforce referential integrity for this relationship.*

I've searched, but couldn't find any solutions to this. Any ideas on how this relationship could be configured?

Comment: user_id is the primary key in users?

Comment: I created what you have above and had no issues is there any details missing?

Comment: Don't forget the CHECK constraint or Table Validation Rule to ensure that author_id <> reviewer_id ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add two individual relationships from one table to two different fields in another, you need to have multiple instances of the parent table in the relationship window.

So, you'd add your Users and Documents table to the relationships window and create the first relationship. Then add the Users table to the relationship window a second time (it will be aliased as Users_1), and then add the second relationship from this aliased copy.

This is completely consistent with the same way you'd define two such joins in the QBE, so I'd say it's not problematic at all. But it's not necessarily obvious!

Comment: I see how that works, thanks! A quick follow question then - in what situations would you use multiple rows in the "Edit Relationships" window?

Comment: +1 for your hostile "consistently unintuitive" remark about the Access UI tools :)

Comment: @GuinesseFan in the relationship window if you just drag the column from one table to the other it creates the second aliased table for you.

Comment: Interpreting my comment as "consistently unintuitive", while perhaps amusing, is not by any means what I suggested. And if you take the QBE as the more familiar user interface for creating joins, you'd realize that adding a second table instance makes more since, since creating two join lines between two tables creates a two-field join, which is not something that is enforceable or creatable in Jet/ACE RI. To create independent joins in the QBE, you add a second instance of the other table, precisely as you do in the relationships window. There is nothing counterintuitive there at all.

Comment: "a two-field join, which is not something that is enforceable or creatable in Jet/ACE RI" -- What does this mean? RI = referential integrity, right? But what has that got to do with a JOIN? You can indeed enforce RI on two-field key, of course. Perhaps 'RI' is a typo for 'UI'?

Comment: Yes, you're write -- that was a brain far on my part. But it's still completely consistent with the way the QBE works, in that if it's a single relation with multiple columns, you have one instance for each table, whereas if it's two different independent relations, you have to have two instances of one of the tables. In the present case, it was two independent relations and thus adding a 2nd table instance is the approach that is completely consistent with the QBE, which is a core Access UI component.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but if I were you I would use another data model to implement the complex many-to-many relation between `Documents` and `Users` by creating a third table called `DocumentsUsers` with the following fields:

```
PK  documentUser_id (*)
FK  document_id
FK  user_id
    documentUser_type

(*) or you could alternatively use document_id + user_id as a PK...
```

The documentUser_type field will hold the relation type, ie 'user', 'reviewer', etc. By using this model, you could have, for the same book, multiple users and/or multiple reviewer, which might be closer to reality. You could even have other relation types like 'author', etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you change you columns' names to `author_user_id` and `reviewer_user_id` respectively, to make it clear that each reference `user_id`.

Second, you should be aware that use of Access's UI tools are not compulsory. Many of us find them unintuitive but happily there are alternatives. One is to use SQL DDL e.g. [ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access/HP030704831033.aspx):

```
ALTER TABLE Documents ADD 
   CONSTRAINT fk__ document_author_user_id__Users
   FOREIGN KEY (author_user_id)
   REFERENCES Users (user_id)
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION
;

ALTER TABLE Documents ADD 
   CONSTRAINT fk__ reviewer_user_id__Users
   FOREIGN KEY (reviewer_user_id)
   REFERENCES Users (user_id)
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION
;
```

Third, consider you may need a `CHECK` constraint (or Table[sic] Validation Rule) to ensure a user cannot review their own work e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE Documents ADD 
   CONSTRAINT document_author_cannot_review_their_own_work
   CHECK (author_user_id <> reviewer_user_id)
;
```